# stackdriver: custom vs log based metrics

Tags: stackdriver

What would be the preferred way to record SLI metric,

1. by creating custom metrics and record the metric update programmatically
2. by write a log entry, define a custom log based metric

Question, looks like #2 could do the same job with no upfront latency, wondering what would be a good use case that #1 better?

Answer (score 0):

Option #2 is better since [log based metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/#stackdriver_monitoring) are based on the content of log entries and they can extract latency information reported in log entries, with [custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics), you must have a metric descriptor for your new metric type.